# Using socket.io to connect to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io

I can't seem to wrap my head around how to submit front end (express) data through socket to mongodb.   I have one simple database with one collection called 'playlist' and two tables called 'youtube_id' and 'upvotes'

The following is in my app.js

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('insertSong', function(song, upvote){
            mongo.connect(MONGO_URL, function(err, db) 
                {
                var playlist = db.collection('playlist');
                playlist.insert({youtube_id: song, upvotes: upvote});

                });
            });


  });
```

and here is the code in my index.html

```
    <script>
                $(function(){
                        var playlist = io();
                        var song = "PEGccV-NOm8";
                        var upvote = 1;
                        playlist.emit('playlist', {song,upvote});


                });
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you successfully send a message over socket yet? Or is that whats failing?

Comment: I used the tutorial to make a simple chat program work with socket so sockets is working & installed and mongodb is also up & running.   I don't receive any errors and nothing is added to the database when i run the frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are emiting a 'playlist' event in your client and waiting for a 'insertSong' on your server.